# what storage should i read cookie, local, session?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, local-storage, session-variables

I am a newbie wrt cookies / local storage/ session storage.

I have a WordPress shop site . I did not like its homepage so I created one with HTML and CSS. here are locations.

```
http://mydomain/index.html (my homepage)
http://mydomain/shop/ (WordPress installation directory)
```

There is a cart icon on WordPress shop. this contains the number of items on the cart. I want to create a similar icon on the homepage. and I want to get the count in the cart item.

I saw in chrome inspector that, when I am on the shop pages the "session storage" and cookies contain the count value ( in unencrypted form). even the local storage has a cart key value pair but its content is encrypted `e.g wc_cart_hash_8463xxxxx : 9d22c2d0yyyy`

When the browser window is closed the "session information" is lost. so I think I should use either the cookie or local storage to display count on my icon at the homepage. But the relevant cookie key value is only visible when the browser is at the shop. The local storage however stays stored when the browser is at the homepage, but it is encrypted, unlike cookie and session storage. All I need is that value of count from the shop so that I can use this javascript code on my homepage

```
 var items = 5;
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (items != 0) {
    $(".shoppingbasket").append("<div class=\"basketitems\">" + items + "</div>")
  }
});
```

Please recommend a way for me to accomplish this task? Being a newbie I am open to any suggestions and criticism and queries.

Comment: do not use local storage, pair session and cookie with your php backend to get it working.

Comment: Add some PHP that works with the shopping system to get the items count, then `var items = <?php echo getCount(); ?>`